# Javascript - getElementByID - Error

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error message in my Javascript.

Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference

```
document.getElementById('BS2').style.display='block';
```

What is going on it that sometimes the Element ID is not showing.  Is there a way to check if the element is there then do this else, go to the next line of code?

```
 function showb() { 
    if(document.getElementById('BS1').style.display=='none') { 
        document.getElementById('BS1').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('BS2').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('BS3').style.display='block'; 
        document.getElementById('BS4').style.display='block'; 
    } 
    return false;
 }
```

Sometimes the BS1 is showing, BS3 is Showing and BS4... etc.

Comment: Can't you just test the return value of `getElementById()` and only proceed if it isn't `null`?

Comment: Your DOM haven't loaded yet. Try putting JS code in the bottom of body.

Comment: How could I do that?  Can you do a example for me?

Comment: @volter9 sometimes it will not even show up in the background. no matter where it is placed.

Comment: Could you post your HTML code with `#BS1`? That would be really helpful.

Comment: How is your `showB` function called?

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById() returns an object just like anything else.  You can assign it to a variable and check the null-ness of the variable:

```
var bs1 = document.getElementById('BS1');

if (bs1) {
  .. do stuff if bs1 is present
} else {
  .. do stuff if bs1 is not there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS pointy said in his comment, you should chekc whether there is an element with the desired ID before trying to read its properties. You could use a piece of code like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('BS2'); // or any other ID
if (element) { // if no element is found, this evaluates as a logical false.
    element.style.display='block';
}
```

Getting the element in a variable also has the advantage that your code becomes more readable. And since you use this multiple times, you could create a function to encapsulate that logic. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well if the property style hasn't been modified it means that it is just ("")

`function showb() { 
        if(document.getElementById('BS1').style.display) { 
            document.getElementById('BS1').style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('BS2').style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('BS3').style.display='block'; 
            document.getElementById('BS4').style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }`

it is going to be solved just like that because ("") is a falsy value